# Do injected process' stay true to locks that are created via the injected DLL/code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, locking, dll-injection

I've created a DLL that injects into a piece of software, the purpose of this DLL is to encrypt some data during run time that shouldn't be accessible by others.

Anyways, we've run into an issue where the encryption/decryption process messes up because another thread (I'm assuming) access' this process for it's own encryption/decryption (in the wrong order).

I don't have access to the software's native code.

My question is....

If I were to make an std::mutex to preform locking operations within a class that is created inside of the injected DLL, but called from the original softwares threads... Would these threads abide by the locking scheme of the DLL? I think the answer is yes, I just want to be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to make an std::mutex to preform locking operations within a class that is created inside of the injected DLL, but called from the original softwares threads...

No, because the other thread in the older code won't know about the mutex, much less abide to it. (mutexes don't magically lock the resource, they are just a way for two or many pieces of code to "signal" each other that some of their "group" needs exclusive access to a resource. If any of the pieces of code ignores the discipline, a mutex isn't going to stop it)

Comment: Right but all the data that is being locked is FROM the DLL. I was under the assumption that how mutex works is that... Any code that is wrapped in a mutex lock, can not be run alongside any other code that is wrapped in the same mutex lock (which is what my DLL does). The DLL has it's own class that has a mutex lock (along with other data). The original threads create 1 instance of this class, only 1 ever. Then they make calls to this DLL, who in turn makes calls to this class. Wouldn't by these means, anything within this class that is locked with the mutex be safe?

Comment: If you "convince" the old thread to use a class under your control, then yes, it *should* work if you make your class make use of a mutex.